# Wireshark decrypt and save wireless packets from command line

Tags: encryption, automation, wireshark, tshark, wifi

I have a question that I can't seem to find a complete answer for. This may not be something that is possible, but I am hoping someone will have a solution.

At my work, we process wireless sniffs in wireshark. We have a shell script to merge and filter the files into the forms that we want, but we still have to manually generate a PSK and add it in wireshark preferences to decrypt each file for analysis. I would like to add a line to decrypt the main file before filtering and save it in a decrypted format.

Here is the problem:
I know I can use the -o flag when running tshark to add the psk to the computers decryption keys, but the processing is done on one computer then the files are distributed among many employees for analysis, so I need the files themselves decrypted.

I know I can use aircrack-ng to decrypt pcap files, but we use pcapng files and aircrack does not recognize those.

Is there any solution? It would even help if I could somehow generate a psk from ssid and password and save that as a text file, but there does not even seem to be a clean way to do that.

We use Ubuntu 16.04 as our OS. Wireshark version 2.0.2.

Comment: Possibly better forums might be [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com) or [Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks. I posted it there.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly just append the psk information directly to the *80211_keys* file located in your Wireshark personal configuration folder then distribute that file along with the capture file.  If you don't want (or if users don't want) to overwrite the existing *80211_keys* file, they could set the `WIRESHARK_DATA_DIR` environment variable so the distributed file is used instead when they run Wireshark for this type of analysis.

Refer to the [Wireshark man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark.html) for more information on the various Wireshark environment variables.

If `aircrack-ng` only supports *pcap* files, then I suppose another possible solution might be to simply convert the *pcapng* files to *pcap* using something like [`editcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html), or just change the default capture file format to *pcap* if you're not making use of any of *pcapng*'s features anyway, e.g., you're not capturing on multiple interfaces simultaneously, you don't use packet comments, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately we do need pcapng for its better time stamp resolution, but sharing the configuration file is a pretty good idea. We process batches at once so I could bundle that up.